# Windows cant open mac shared files unless read only

Tags: windows-7, permissions, mac-osx-server, file-sharing

I recently setup a mac server (Mavericks 10.9.5, Server 3.2.1) in our office environment, mostly mac but there are two windows pcs.

The windows 8 machine can connect and open files/folders without issues.

The windows 7 machine can connect and browse folders but cannot open files. I have found a workaround for this, setting the files to read only allows the files to be opened, read and write permissions do not allow for the files to be opened.

The error that I receive is "The file is already in use by another user". The machine is logged in with the main/admin login for the machine and has full permissions. The files are not locked and have full read write permissions.

In short, the problem occurs when:
The computer has full read write access to the files on the server, upon trying to open a file a message says its already in use.

A strange (non-feasible) workaround:
Either locking the file or changing the permissions to read only allows the files to be opened.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Ta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple and completely noobish and yet it has cause me two weeks of pain.

A bit of background on the issue, the windows pc could connect within the first week of the server operation, there after it stopped working (this is where the confusion came in).

**Solution:** Check your antivirus setup, the software that we are using seems to have a realtime file scanning mode, which seems to have been locking the files (when scanning in realtime?), disabling this for network volumes resolved the issue.

Thanks all!